# Fork Issue - After executing fork(), commands before fork are also running twice

Tags: c, linux, fork

Here is the output ---

Parent: my pid is 4525
Parent: my parent's pid is 3350
parant started- 4525    3350
**Before Fork
Before Fork**
 Child 4526 4525
In parent
---Parent End---

When I try to execute the below code ---

```
void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int status;
    pid_t my_pid, parent_pid,child_pid;

    my_pid = getpid();
    parent_pid = getppid();
    printf("\nParent: my pid is %d", my_pid);
    printf("\nParent: my parent's pid is %d", parent_pid);
    printf("\nparant started- %d    %d",my_pid,parent_pid);
    printf("\nBefore Fork");

    if((child_pid = fork()) < 0 )
    {
        perror("fork failure");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(child_pid == 0)
    {
        printf("\n Child %d %d\n",getpid(),getppid());

    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nIn parent");
        wait(&status);
        printf("\n---Parent End---\n");
    }

}
```

Why is the **Before Fork** is printing twice?? Thanks

Comment: ...and `main()` returns `int`, by the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you're not flushing the output buffer prior to the `fork()`. Change to:

```
printf("\nBefore Fork\n");
```

or:

```
printf("\nBefore Fork");
fflush(stdout);
```